# JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks in Android Cordova app

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cordova

I am working on an app which has a XMLHttprequest. I am using cordova-1.7 for Android. I am able to get app working when i send a sync request, but request seems get lost when i send it asynchronously. Sending sync request(which is working) does not allow some other functionalities to work.The error which I am getting from cordova.js file are

06-19 12:14:58.100: D/CordovaLog(816): JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks.
06-19 12:14:58.100: D/CordovaLog(816): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.7.0rc1.js: Line 3560 : JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks.
06-19 12:14:58.100: I/Web Console(816): JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.7.0rc1.js:3560

Async request used to work properly on iPhone(iOS). Anybody has any idea, will be helpful for me. Please let me know if more details are required.

Thanks

The part of code is as follows:-
    {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getXmlDoc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", 'URL', 'true', uid, pwd);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

Rest is that, it is being used for Android. I am using Cordova-1.7 for device feature accessibility. Also the same request works in iPhone. Here in Android only sync works, async does not works. Also the URL beign used is Https one.
Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: @SimonMacDonald    The part of code is as follows:- { xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getXmlDoc; xmlhttp.open("GET", 'URL', 'true', uid, pwd); xmlhttp.send(null); } Rest is that, it is being used for Android. I am using Cordova-1.7 for device feature accessibility. Also the same request works in iPhone. Here in Android only sync works, async does not works. Also the URL beign used is Https one. Any insight?